# WPF CollectionViewSource Data Display Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, collectionviewsource

I have a ComboBox setup to display a bound list of ApplicationNames. The list type the ComboBox is bound to is `ObservableCollection<Apps>`. I am using a CollectionViewSource to do the sorting as so:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="Apps"
    Source="{Binding Path=Apps}"
    >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="AppNames" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The ComboBox is written as:

```
<ComboBox
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                DataContext="{StaticResource Apps}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ApplicationItemStyle}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource applicationComboTemplate}"
                >
            </ComboBox>
```

Now when I open the View that houses this combobox all the application names display properly in the combobox and are sorted. The issue I am having is when I close that view and then re-open the view. When I re-open the view everything loads exactly as it did the first-time, in the way of how I get the ObervableCollection, but this time around nothing shows up in the ComboBox. Also, in the ViewModel I do clear the collection and remove all registered events when the View and ViewModel close.

Here is where I close:

```
void CleanUpApps()
{
   if (this.Apps != null)
   {
       foreach (var app in this.Apps)
            app.Dispose();

       this.Apps.Clear();
       this.Apps.CollectionChanged -= OnAppsCollectionChanged;
   }
}
```

If I copy `{Binding Path=Apps}` from the CollectionViewSource and place it over `{StaticResource Apps}` in the ComboBoxes DataContext, everything works, except the sort now of course, the first time I open the view and every time after.

I am trying to find out what I am doing wrong in the CollectionViewSource, that is causing the second time around loading the view to not have any application names display in the combobox.

Comment: Let see some code where you do the clearing when it is closed

Comment: Are you sure the `Apps` has value after you reopen the window? Do you played with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` (_true_ or _false_) in your `ComboBox`?

Comment: @RAM Yes, Apps has a value when re-opening. I can open and close the View over and over again and the ComboBox displays the data when I do not use `CollectionViewSource` and actually use the `{Binding Apps}` in the DataContext but when I use the `CollectionViewSource` the re-opening of the View/Window refuses to show any data in the combobox. I have tried both `true` and `false` for the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`. This is such a weird issue.

Comment: I recommend you try using `CollectionViewSource` in code-behind inside your `VM` class or behind your `Window`... Is it works when you use it in code-behind? There are some good samples [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html). Check your code at run-time by putting several breakpoints in some specific points.

Comment: @RAM In the VM I added the public property `ICollectionView IApps` and have it return `_apps = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Apps);`. Then changed the DataContext to point to this new property. Once I did this, I could open and close the view as many times as I wanted and it still populated properly. So I am really confused why it works, always, when building the CollectionViewSource in the VM but not in the V when just using XAML.

Comment: I'm happy... but really i don't know what happen when you use it in `Xaml` instead of `Code-Behind`. I think it related to a mistake about `Binding` issue or your other code side effect on the `CollectionViewSource` result...